# declaration of member variables in ES6 classes

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've seen member variables in ES6 declared like this

```
export class MyClass
{
   x = null;

   constructor()  {
      this.x = 1;
   }

   write() {
      console.log(this.x);
   }
}
```

and babel seem to transpile it fine.

Is this a valid way to declare member variables?

Comment: There is no such thing as "member variables" in JS. And what you have seen is not ES6, but an experimental feature proposal for ES8. Don't use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the suggestion for [ES Class Fields & Static Properties](https://github.com/jeffmo/es-class-fields-and-static-properties).
It's supported by babeljs, with this [plugin](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/).
It's a babel stage-1 plugin, so if you're using stage-1 or stage-0, this is supported.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe this is correct. At least, the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) does not mention any such syntax.

As for your example, let's work through it line by line.

```
class MyClass { // Class declaration, all good here
   x = null; // I assume you're telling javascript that the variable x exists?

   constructor()  {
      this.x = 1; // You do that here just fine.
   }

   write() {
      console.log(this.x); // And here we use the variable, after the constructor ran
   }
}
```

I don't see any value in declaring the member variables seperately. You create it in the constructor. That should be all you need